# Crop selected path area from custom image view

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap

I have created custom image view for remove a selected part from bitmap images. 
There are operation for select area to get rid from current bitmap by a [path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) has a collection of [points](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html).

Here it is code snippet :

```
      for (int i = points.size() - 2; i < points.size(); i++) {
                        if (i >= 0) {
                            Point point = points.get(i);

                            if (i == 0) {
                                Point next = points.get(i + 1);
                                point.dx = ((next.x - point.x) / 3);
                                point.dy = ((next.y - point.y) / 3);
                            } else if (i == points.size() - 1) {
                                Point prev = points.get(i - 1);
                                point.dx = ((point.x - prev.x) / 3);
                                point.dy = ((point.y - prev.y) / 3);
                            } else {
                                Point next = points.get(i + 1);
                                Point prev = points.get(i - 1);
                                point.dx = ((next.x - prev.x) / 3);
                                point.dy = ((next.y - prev.y) / 3);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            path.cubicTo(prev.x + prev.dx, prev.y + prev.dy, point.x -  point.dx, 
                                             point.y - point.dy, point.x, point.y);

            paramCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Look at this output:

[image]

I used [clip path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipPath(android.graphics.Path)) to get crop this part but this not working for me.

I am getting stuck to clip that selected part so can you help me out to solve this thing.
I would greatly appreciated any help. Thanks